# RabbitMQ permissions doesn't apply

Tags: java, permissions, rabbitmq, amazon-mq

i'm setting permissions for a specific user, and get:

`Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'my-queue' in vhost 'myVHost' refused for user 'myUser', class-id=50, method-id=20)`

My permissions contain multiple queues and exchanges, and specifically the relevant queue gets the **configure** + **write** + **read** permissions:

`^first$|^second$|^my-queue$`

and still, i get that error.

even if i try:
`configure: .*`
`write: .*`
`read: ^my-queue$`
i get the same error message.

i've spent many hours reading about how to set up the permissions and i have some experience with it, but no luck.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At the end it was the pod's connection to rabbit that was not reset and therefor kept the original settings.